# Re-position locate me button on google maps [Android]

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, android-maps-v2, locate

I have a bottom sheet that has a visible peak of 200dp. I positioned the locate me button of google map over the bottom sheet, like this:

[image]

Sometimes i need to dismiss the bottom sheet, and I want to re-position the locate me button. To do this I call the same code which I called to position first the button, with different  value for bottom:

```
 val rlp = locationButton.layoutParams as (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
        rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0)
        rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE)
        rlp.setMargins(0, 0, 30, bottomValue)
```

I have debuged and the `locationButton` position has new values, but it is still on the same position, so the map looks like this:

[image]

What I possible do wrong?

Comment: May be `rlp.setMargins(0, 0, 30, bottomValue)` line is redundant.

Comment: but when i first call that `code` the button is positioned different case of `bottomValue` ; when I recall the `code` to re-position the button with a different value for `bottomValue` the button still lays in the same place @AndriiOmelchenko